# Does autoconf discover header files present on system?

Tags: path, header-files, autoconf

I am trying to setup a project to build with GNU autotools. One of my sources files has the following header file directive:

`#include<lapacke.h>`.

On an OpenSUSE machine, `lapacke.h` is in installed in `/usr/include/openblas/`, but this location does not hold for other distributions.

In my `configure.ac` file, I check whether this header file is available:

`AC_CHECK_HEADERS([fcntl.h float.h inttypes.h limits.h stdint.h stdlib.h string.h unistd.h lapacke.h],,AC_MSG_ERROR([required header file missing]))`

The configure script fails to locate `lapacke.h` without additional hints. 

`checking lapacke.h usability... no
checking lapacke.h presence... no
checking for lapacke.h... no
configure: error: 
required header file missing`

I can manually specify the directory `./configure CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/openblas"` and succeed. Do end users have to manually submit the path to look for `lapacke.h`, or is there a way for autoconf to discover this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do end users have to manually submit the path to look for lapacke.h, or is there a way for autoconf to discover this automatically?

This is something that autoconf can be told, but not necessarily figure out by itself automatically, e.g.:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([fcntl.h float.h inttypes.h limits.h stdint.h stdlib.h string.h unistd.h],,AC_MSG_ERROR([required header file missing]))
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([openblas/lapacke.h lapacke.h],,AC_MSG_ERROR([required header file missing]))
```